# Fatal error: Can't compare indices belonging to different collections:

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I'm getting a strange error when iterating over the contents of a SwiftyJSON object.

I initialise the object and pass to a function which converts the JSON to a dictionary suitable for a POST request

```
var routineForUpload:JSON = [:]
    
routineForUpload["Make"] = JSON("")
routineForUpload["Model"] = JSON("")
routineForUpload["EndYear"] = JSON("")
routineForUpload["StartYear"] = JSON("")
doPostOperation(routineForUpload)

func doPostOperation(_ inputJSON:JSON){
    ....
    var post = [String: String]()
    for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in inputJSON { //<-- ** Error appears here **
        post[key] = subJson.stringValue
    }
    .... 
}
```

When I initalise the object with three properties everything works, when I increase to four my app crashes with:

Fatal error: Can't compare indices belonging to different collections:

When I trace the error it points to this function in SwiftyJSON.swift

```
public func ==(lhs: JSONIndex, rhs: JSONIndex) -> Bool
{
    switch (lhs, rhs)
    {
    case (.array(let left), .array(let right)):
        return left == right
    case (.dictionary(let left), .dictionary(let right)):
        return left == right //<- ** Error appears here **
    case (.null, .null): return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this is something to do with checking if the iteration is complete but I'm a bit stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have resolved the issue by using

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in inputJSON.dictionaryValue {
```

instead of

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in inputJSON {
```